# Is it normal to smell gas near a gas range?

Tags: leak, gas, propane, range

I recently extended our LP gas line to the kitchen so I could install a gas range. Since I'm technically not a qualified professional, I had the gas company come and test the line for leaks. There was a small leak detected which I was told was "about half a pound after 9 minutes" (I'm not sure what this even means). He said it's within the legal standard but I said I wanted the leaks fixed. He ended up making sure the fittings were all tight and had no noticeable leaks with an electric detector and said it was good to go.

This morning, I noticed that when I put my head over the range I could smell a little gas that was very noticeable if I wafted it to my nose. I could also smell a little gas when I opened the bottom drawer. I should mention that last night I was showing my wife how it works and I turned a burner on without igniting it to show her that the gas will just come out. This was only for a few seconds. Is it normal to smell a little gas with a gas range? Could it be that I'm just smelling the residual gas from the previous night? I'm not sure if I should call a plumber to check for leaks.

Note: Location is US

Comment: What make and model is your gas range? Have you checked fir known issues with the specific appliance?

Comment: @Kris The gas range is a Whirlpool WEG750H0HV. This [link](https://www.whirlpool.com/kitchen/cooking/ranges/slide-in/p.5.8-cu.-ft.-smart-slide-in-gas-range-with-ez-2-lift-hinged-cast-iron-grates.weg750h0hv.html) is from the manufacturers website.

Comment: Well, question Number one (which may not apply, but if it does, it's the most common cause) is whether this range is standing pilot, or electronic ignition. Standing pilot ranges with one or more pilot lights out are a common cause of "slight gas leak"

Comment: @Ecnerwal it is an electric ignition

Comment: if you have to work to smell gas, it's not dangerous because it's designed to be smelled long before it's concentrated enough to explode. While it might waste a tiny bit of money over the long-haul, it's not a drop-everything emergency, especially in a kitchen where it won't collect (like it could in a closet or basement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't normal, and any gas in the room should dissipate fairly quickly. Get yourself a cup of soapy water and a paint brush and find the leak. At the very least your house will smell bad. At worst....

Comment: The gas company worker said that it seemed like the electronic detector was going off near one of the parts on the gas range, like past the initial connection. Would I be better off hiring a plumber? Or is there someone else that would specialize in this?

Comment: That's entirely up to you and your motivation. You'd want an HVAC technician, not a plumber (though some plumbers will do gas).

Comment: Thank you for the HVAC clarification. What is an acceptable level of gas leaking?

Comment: That's a subjective question also. For me? Zero ppm. :P

Comment: If you think the appliance is leaking and it’s new, then arrange warranty service.  If you think the appliance is leaking and it’s used then seek paid appliance service.  If you think your plumbing job is leaking, find that with the soapy water test as @isherwood describes.  If you need to decide which, close the service valve you installed just before the stove connection and wait to re-sniff. Most new appliances don’t have a continuous pilot light, however if you have a continuous pilot light that might be the source of the oder.

Comment: @Programmer In the UK, with all appliances disconnected the maximum acceptable pressure drop when the pipework is disconnected from the mains is zero.  With a new appliance connected, the maximum acceptable pressure drop is still zero.  Existing appliances are allowed up to 4mb pressure drop provided there is no smell of gas.

Comment: @MartinBonner I should specify I'm in the US.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, I guessed that - but your gas goes BANG! just as impressively as ours does, so I thought it would still be a useful datapoint.

Comment: @MartinBonner Your comment was actually very helpful for me in determining that I am not personally comfortable with ANY leak if some countries do not allow it at all. I am just curious what the US standard is. The gas company guy said it was something like no noticeable drop for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a gas oven, but I always had gas ranges and never had gas smell coming from it. 
My suggestion is to buy a gas-leak detector and put it in a reasonable place (next to the ceiling if you're on methane or next to the floor if you're on LPG as LPG is heavier then air and methane is lighter). 
Also add a proper permanent venting hole to the room (UNI rules require 6 cm^2/kW) with a minimum 100cm^2. The vent should be placed at an height suitable for the gas used (next to the ceiling if methane or next to the floor if LPG).

I really think your new appliance has some defect, so ask for warranty fix.