# Who should I call to service my gas line?

Tags: repair, leak, appliances, gas

I think I have a small LP gas leak at my new gas range. I don't know if it's the appliance or the new gas line. Who should I call that can check and service this? I was previously told to call an HVAC company but I did and they said to call the appliance repair company. I called the appliance repair company and they said they can service the appliance but MIGHT not be able to service the gas line. I don't want to call two different companies.

For context and more information, [see my previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147998/is-it-normal-to-smell-gas-near-a-gas-range?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Did you do the install or did the store that sold it to you?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I did the install.

Comment: Did you try the soapy water that Isherwood suggested in your other question to identify the location of the leak?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I did and I could not find any visible leaks.

Comment: Is there a shutoff immediately before the appliance? If so, did you shut it off and smell test a good while later?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I had the gas company come out and test it for leaks. There was a leak behind the appliance but he said he fixed it. However, his leak detector wand was still sensing some gas but at a very small level, like it wouldn't even produce bubbles so he said it was probably his device detecting residual gas.

Comment: Plumbers run gas lines, but don’t service appliances generally, and vice versa.

Comment: @Tyson I think your comment on Isherwood's post is basically what I was getting at. You should post that as an answer over here.

Comment: Good point @UnhandledExcepSean I’ll do that shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stringing us along and telling the full story question by question.  Your other related question, which contains important information not included here can be found [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147998/is-it-normal-to-smell-gas-near-a-gas-range)

If you think the appliance is leaking and it’s new, then arrange warranty service.

If you think the appliance is leaking and it’s used then seek paid appliance service.  (choices 1 and 2 are often very different companies. Companies performing factory direct warranty service are usually very expensive for consumers after warranty, in which case your better off to find the local appliance repair guy, or someone that has worked in the industry before.

If you think your plumbing job is leaking, find that with the soapy water test as [@isherwood describes in the posted answer to that question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/148001/53243).

If you need to decide which to fix/test, close the service valve you installed just before the stove connection and wait to re-sniff.

Most new appliances don’t have a continuous pilot light, however if you have a continuous pilot light that might be the source of the oder. Sometimes cleaning a carbon buildup helps, or strengthening (warming) the pilot.  I'm told that that oderant added to the gas doesn't completely burn itself up in a small relatively cool pilot flame, when the burner ignites it typically produces a enough hot flame to completely destroy the oder. (My source for the above was a gas fireplace repair guy, he sold me a new pilot assembly and it did seem to decrease the pilot only oder greatly.)

As far as the appliance service company stating they may not help with the gas line, I don't blame them.  They don't know without seeing if it was done professionally to code or if installed in a dodgy fashion.  If they miss something and it later catches fire that's on them.

Close the gas valve and decide if it's your gas line. If so, use the soap test until you locate the leak (this is very easy to do).  if you need appliance service call the company back instead.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. As a side note, my intention wasn't to string you along question by question. I felt my first post asked a completely different question than this one and I didn't want to muddy the waters (or posts).

Comment: You’re correct it is a completely different question.  A good thing to do when continuing a question tho is to reference the last, so that missing facts come forward.  I read here frequently so I connected the two quickly, others may find this question first and not have the whole story.

Comment: Ahh, good point. I'll add a link in my post then.